# Getting previous column values in a new column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table, named Example:

```
 col1   
 ----------
 101   
 102   
 103   
 104
```

I want below result existing column with one addition result

```
col1   newcol
---------------
 101   0/''/null
 102   101
 103   102
 104   103


 SELECT COL1, @a := @a AS col2
 FROM MYTABLE JOIN (SELECT @a := 0) t
 ORDER BY COL1;
```

Can I get the previous column value in the second column corresponding 
  to the first column

Comment: How do you want to determine what is the previous column? Numerically sorted?

Comment: @amber, based on some other column the values will appear like this, yes numerically stored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `a` to save the last one.

```
SELECT @a as Prev, @a:=COL1 as Current
FROM MYTABLE
ORDER BY COL1;
```

You can find further information in [MySQL User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)

I hope that you will find it useful.

**EDITED**:

Removed the initializing sentence of @a:

```
SET @a=0;
```

First value of @a will be NULL

Comment: MySQL specifically warns against using and assigning variables in different expressions in the same select.  And, in fact, sometimes this doesn't work, because the order of evaluation is not guaranteed.

Comment: I rearranged the code..       SELECT @a as Prev, @a:=COL1 as Current
FROM MYTABLE,(SELECT @a := 0) x
ORDER BY COL1; thanks @Gordon Linoff thanks @ David Isla

Comment: This is still problematic: you are setting and using `@a` variable in the same `SELECT`.

Comment: oh..ok..anyway..thanks @Giorgos Betsos, will take care of this

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos mmmm... I see...then I need read more about this behavior.. thanks both! Upvote for Gordon ;)

Comment: @syncdm2012 read Gordon's answer if you want user vars to achieve yor sentence! Good luck!

Comment: You can check the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html): *For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. In the following statement, you might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an assignment second:...*

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I was looking for it! Thanks!!

Comment: Anyone reading this answer should be aware that it is not guaranteed to work.  The problem is the use of the same variable in two expressions in the `select`.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `SELECT`, so this might work or might not work.  See my answer for a correct version.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit complicated, but the following handles it:

```
SELECT COL1,
       (CASE WHEN (@oldprev := @prev) = NULL THEN NULL -- NEVER HAPPENS
             WHEN (@prev := col1) = NULL THEN NULL     -- NEVER HAPPENS
             ELSE @oldprev
        END) as prevcol
FROM MYTABLE CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @prev := 0) params
ORDER BY COL1;
```

As a note:  `oldprev` doesn't need to be initialized because its value is used only in the `case`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.`col1` AS col1,
(IFNULL(T2.`col2`,0)) AS new_col
FROM
table_name T1 LEFT JOIN table_name T2 ON T1.`col1`=(T2.`col1` - 1)
```

Comment: (T2.`col1` - 1) may not work , as its not necessary the values will be serial,yes in the example it is shown serially(100,101,102..) but real time may be 201,101,502,302...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a correlated sub-query:

```
SELECT col1, (SELECT col1 
              FROM mytable AS t2
              WHERE t2.col1 < t1.col1
              ORDER BY col1 DESC LIMIT 1) AS newcol
FROM mytable AS t1
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76d45/3)

**Note:** The query works as long as `col1` doesn't contain any duplicates.